# typescript string enum, reverse mapping equivalent

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a string enum and need to check if a literal pertains to the enum. Reverse mapping does not work on string enums.

Supposing

```
enum Animals{
    cat="c";
    dog="d";
    fish="f";
}

let animal= "d";
```

is animal a member of Animals ?
Considering the enum an object you can iterate and check:

```
function inEnum(what, enu):boolean{
    for (let item in enu){
        if (enu[item]==what){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there a better way?, may this technique break in future versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the question directly, it's worth just mentioning that TypeScript supports a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) which is often a better fit for this type of thing than a string `enum`. Example:

```
type Animal = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'fish';

let myAnimal1: Animal = 'cat'; // ok
let myAnimal2: Animal = 'buttercup'; // compile-time error "'buttercup' is not assignable to type Animal"
```

This type of approach has the benefit of letting you know at *compile*-time whether a value is valid for the `Animals` type.

---

Now, to answer your question about determining if a value is in an `enum` at *run*-time, we have the `in` operator which we can use to refactor your `inEnum` function as follows:

```
let inEnum = (val, enumObj) => val in enumObj;

inEnum("d", Animals) //evaluates to true
inEnum("z", Animals) //evaluates to false
```

or even drop the function call altogether and just use the `in` operator directly:

```
"d" in Animals //evaluates to true
"z" in Animals //evaluates to false
```

There is, however, nothing to suggest that your own approach above would ever break in future versions.

Comment: With the in operator it's even cleaner using it directly instead of calling a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `ts-enum-util` ([github](https://github.com/UselessPickles/ts-enum-util), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-enum-util)) lib supports validation of enum names/values and type-safe value->key and key->value lookups with run-time validation and the option to either throw an error or return a default value.

Examples:

```
import {$enum} from "ts-enum-util";

enum Animals{
    cat="c";
    dog="d";
    fish="f";
}

let animal= "d"; 

// true
const isAnimal = $enum(Animals).isValue(animal);

// the "isValue" method is a custom type guard
if ($enum(Animals).isValue(animal)) {
    // type of "animal" in here is "Animals" instead of "string"
}

// type: ("cat" | "dog" | "fish")
// value: "dog"
const name = $enum(Animals).getKeyOrThrow(animal);
```